# How to run within a Python code a bash command like "python script.py --arg1 1 --arg2 2"

Tags: python, bash

I have a script which is basically run through Bash, using :

```
python3 script.py --arg1 1 --arg2 2
```

For more context, this [script is from Huggingface in order to fine-tune NLP models](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/run_language_modeling.py).

The Python code is something like :

```
def main():
    parser = HfArgumentParser((ModelArguments, DataTrainingArguments, TrainingArguments)) # custom parser
    model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses() # custom method
    (...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question is :

How to run `main()` from within a Python code ? Is bash syntax equivalent to using a dictionary ?

Example :

```
import script

script.main({'arg1' : 1, 'arg2' : 2})
```

Comment: You can't. If the main is like here, then it doesn't allow any arguments. Commandline arguments are parsed inside the main, not before and forwarded. So you'll have to basically write a function like that main but parse stuff manually before executing what you need to execute with those.

Comment: Looking into the source code of `parse_args_into_dataclasses()` I find that it takes an argument `args` (`List of strings to parse. The default is taken from sys.argv.`). What you suggest is sending my own arguments in this function using `args` , if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yep. What I suggest is basically copying main and giving args manually. Basically the only change would be: `parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()` -> `parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses("--arg1 1 --arg2 2".split())` Explanation: argparse parsers require args in format of argv, that is a list of strings. If you don't have multi-word arguments quoted, putting whole thing in there and doing .split() is the easiest to convert it to correct format. Docs actually use split a lot in examples - https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks. What you say is that I can just pass a well constructed list. Pretty cool as I thought I needed to build my own clean `args` like in this Stack Overflow answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664254/4974431

Comment: Nah. In that answer you linked, parser is being constructed - while you already have parser (not yours, with this custom method to convert to dataclass) and just need to give it what it needs to parse~